# Get self reference column

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have employee table

```
+----+------+--------------+--------------+
| Id | Name | SupervisorId | IsSupervisor |
+----+------+--------------+--------------+
```

and supervisor table

```
+----+---------+
| Id | Section |
+----+---------+
```

And what I want is to make this table

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| EmployeeID | EmployeeName | SupervisorId | SupervisorName |
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Supervisor should be empty if not exist

My query ended up with something like this line with question mark is the one hat need to be replaced

```
Select
  employees.Id as EmployeeID,
  employees.Name as EmployeeName,
  supervisors.Id as SupervisorId,
  supervisors.Name as SupervisorName # ???
From
  employees Left Join
  supervisors
    On employees.SupervisorId = supervisors.Id
```

Comment: supervisors table doesn't have a name column!!??

Comment: @AbdullahWasi no you need to get the name from employee table by checking IsSupervisor column

Comment: it looks to be redundant: if an employee can be a supervisor, then `EmployeeName` and `SupervisorName` will be the same. What's the benefits?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I thought SupervisorName will always be different from Employee's name, if he is Supervisor then he won't have a supervisorid his id is someone else's supervisorid...i could be wrong though

Comment: @TinTran thats exactly correct, I didn't design the database I just using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, getting supervisor's name out of Employees(E2) table.

```
Select
    E.Id as EmployeeID,
    E.Name as EmployeeName,
    S.Id as SupervisorId,
    E2.Name as SupervisorName
From
    Employees E 
    Left Join
    Supervisors S On E.SupervisorId = S.Id
    Left Join
    Employees E2 On E2.Id = S.Id
```

Comment: I think you might need to make that inner join also a left join.